# HTML placing elements in the same row

Tags: html, css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following form for uploading files (using some Bootstrap css) in Asp.NET MVC. Right now the "Clear" button is *below* the input field; how to make it to the right of the input-field?

I thought about using `<table>` and have one column for the input fields and one for the buttons, but it doesn't seem suitable and Visual Studio gave me the squiggly lines when i tried.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Uploader", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="file" name="files" id="file1" />
        <button onclick="reset2($('#file1'));event.preventDefault()">Clear</button>
        <span class="field-validation-error" id="err1"></span>
        @Html.ValidationMessage("1")
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="file" name="files" id="file2" />
        <button onclick="reset2($('#file2'));event.preventDefault()">Clear</button>
        <span class="field-validation-error" id="err2"></span>
        @Html.ValidationMessage("2")
    </div>
... more file input fields
}
```

Comment: Use css. There are numerous ways this could be done, for example `display: inline-block;` or `float: left;` or using [positioning](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp)

Comment: An `input` element and a `button` element are placed on the same line unless there is something special that causes a line break, probably a CSS rule. Please show actual HTML and CSS code that reproduce the issue.

Comment: if you are using bootstrap then there is a class called pull-right to do this job. Do some googling...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple `style="display:inline"` on the input will work as follows;

```
   <div class="form-group">
     <input type="file" name="files" id="file1" style="display:inline" />
        <button onclick="reset2($('#file1'));event.preventDefault()">Clear</button>
        <span class="field-validation-error" id="err1"></span>

    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="file" name="files" id="file2" style="display:inline" />
        <button onclick="reset2($('#file2'));event.preventDefault()">Clear</button>
        <span class="field-validation-error" id="err2"></span>

    </div>
```

I'm sure that some will have a better answer than mine that is more bootstrap specific however.

**[Fiddle](http://www.bootply.com/K0jjQAyDNf)**

**Screen grab**

[image]